# Phpmyadmin setup "allow from" and ".htaccess password" not working together

Tags: php, apache-2.4, .htaccess, centos7

Im following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-with-apache-on-a-centos-7-server) from digitalocean and i have sucessfully setup the require ip and allow ip so that only my ip address can connect to the webpage.

However, on the last part setting up the Web Server Authentication Gate, when i enable the htaccess and create the htpasswd, it disables the restiction on the ip address so that every ip can connect to it.

When i then remove the htaccess file, the web login works again.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the tutorial on both, you'll have (second from `.htaccess`):

```
Require ip your_workstation_IP_address
Require valid-user
```

From mod_authz_core [`Require` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) documentation:

> When multiple `Require` directives are used in a single [configuration
>   section](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging) and are not contained in another authorization directive like
>   `<RequireAll>`, they are implicitly contained within a `<RequireAny>`
>   directive. Thus the first one to authorize a user authorizes the
>   entire request, and subsequent `Require` directives are ignored.

And about [merging](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#merging):

> `<Directory>` (except regular expressions) and `.htaccess` done
>   simultaneously (with `.htaccess`, if allowed, overriding `<Directory>`)

If you really need both the rules:

1. Have them in the same configuration section.
2. Place them inside `<RequireAll>`.

But really, if you already have `Require ip` limited to one (or few) IP address(es) and the PhpMyAdmin login form, the `Require valid-user` won't practically add any extra layer of security.

---

The tutorial misses one crucial step, more important than any of these `Require` statements:

> However, your phpMyAdmin interface will be available at the new location we selected:
>
> ```
> http://server_domain_or_IP/nothingtosee
> ```

## Only serve your PhpMyAdmin secured by TLS!

This should really be `https://server_domain_or_IP/nothingtosee`. It's important as otherwise you might reveal your database logins and leak all the data in the databases. Enable HTTPS e.g. by using free [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) certificates and following Apache's [SSL/TLS Strong Encryption: How-To](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help, in that case i think ill remove the login requirement and just the use IP as you suggested.

Comment: That's how I do it for some customers in need of web based access to their databases, luckily having static IP addresses on their company network. Please also read my additional note from my edit as it's vital.

Comment: Oh yes, Thank you, I have already changed the url to just a random string of characters. I have also used Lets Encrypt to secure it with SSL.
Thank you very much for your help.